# Understanding command line OpenSSL DGST Sha256 command

Tags: hash, command-line, openssl, sha

I have the command `openssl dgst -sha256 -binary _your_file_path_ | openssl enc -base64` I use in terminal to get an output for a jar file that matches what AWS Lambda uses to hash.

I want to program that in Java, but I am having trouble understanding exactly what is going on in that line, so that I can go through each step in my code. Obviously, there is mode than just hashing in SHA256, because when I do that the output does not match.

Could someone help explain the steps that line is completing in a simple way for me?

Answer (score 3):

You need to break the command down to understand what is going on.

1. The first part of the command:

   - `openssl dgst -sha256 -binary <file>` gives you a SHA256 *binary* checksum for the file.
2. The second part of the command:

   - `openssl enc -base64` encodes the SHA256 binary checksum to Base64.

So to replicate in Java, you just need to carry out those same steps:

1. Calculate a SHA256 *binary* checksum.
2. Base64 encode the SHA256 binary checksum.

Without you posting the command you used to try and get a SHA256 checksum separately to the command you did post, I'm guessing the reason you were probably getting a different hash is because by default a checksum seems to output in hexadecimal.

See my example below and how the results are completely different.

```sh
# Hexadecimal
$ openssl dgst -sha256 data.csv
SHA256(data.csv)= 114811b0b8998cb9853a5379598021410feddf69bb2ee7b7145d052a7e9b5d45

# Binary (note the usage of the -binary flag)
$ openssl dgst -sha256 -binary data.csv
H:SyY!Ai.]*~]E
```

If you then Base64 encode the hexadecimal checksum above, and the binary one, you'll also get two completely different results, as you can see below.

```sh
# Hexadecimal
$ printf 114811b0b8998cb9853a5379598021410feddf69bb2ee7b7145d052a7e9b5d45 | openssl enc -base64
MTE0ODExYjBiODk5OGNiOTg1M2E1Mzc5NTk4MDIxNDEwZmVkZGY2OWJiMmVlN2I3
MTQ1ZDA1MmE3ZTliNWQ0NQ==

# Binary
$ printf 'H:SyY!Ai.]*~]E' | openssl enc -base64
SDpTeVkhQWkuXSp+XUU=
```

Comment: It would be good to add a link to a definition/spec (or at least a descriptive README) for the binary format if you know it. I need to find it myself at the moment so will set off to look, but suspect I might just end up browsing the openssl source-code, again...

Comment: Following up on my own comment, so far it looks like the SHA digests are the network-order/bigendian X-bit number (e.g. 256-bit, 512-bit), and the hexadecimal representation of those numbers for text-output. If wrong, will comment again later.

Answer (score 0):

For those, who TLDR. 
 To get the same result as in this `cat FILENAME.js | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl base64 -A` command you should do the following conversions:

```
1) your content -> sha256 (you'll get the hexadecimal number, not a text)
2) hexadecimal -> binary
3) binary -> base64
```